# std::map::rend() returning first element of array, not element before

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I'm trying to reverse iterate through a std::map, following this code: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/rend/
It says:

> rend() returns a reverse iterator referring to the element right before the first element in the map container, which is considered its reverse end.
>
> Notice that rend does not refer to the same element as begin, but to the element right before it.

```
map<float,int> m;
m.insert(pair<float,int>(.1,0));
m.insert(pair<float,int>(.4,5));
map<float,int>::reverse_iterator rend=m.rend();
map<float,int>::iterator begin=m.begin();
```

When I run this, both rend and begin point to the first element of m, (.1,0), when obviously it shouldn't, given the Notice above.  I feel like there's some very obvious mistake I'm making, but I can't figure out what it could be.

(C++,MSVC2010)

Comment: How are you determining that `rend` "points to" that item?

Comment: That is not a definitive reference.  By what means have you determined where rend is pointing?  If you dereferenced rend, your results are invalid, because that's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the point you are missing is that if you inspect the values using a debugger, the values returned by `rend()` and `begin()` *will* contain the same value. However, the `operator*` members of the iterator types will still give you access to different objects.

Technical details: The value returned by `rend()` cannot point before `begin()`, because that is not valid. So it was decided that `rend()` should contain the value of `begin()` and all other reverse iterators be shifted one position further. The `operator*` compensates for this and accesses the correct element anyway.

First paragraph of 24.5.1 Reverse iterators says:

> Class template reverse_iterator is an iterator adaptor that iterates from the end of the sequence defined by its underlying iterator to the beginning of that sequence. The fundamental relation between a reverse iterator and its corresponding iterator i is established by the identity:
>   `&*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the element that `rend` points to is **undefined behavior**. It very well might give you the first item in the container or crash your application or whatever you can imagine. This element is just a placeholder that is used to signal the end of the container when you are iterating (same applies to the `end` of the various Standard Library containers).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you are checking where `rend` is pointing to, but I ran this example disproving your claim.

```
int main() {

    map<float,int> m;
    m.insert(pair<float,int>(.1,0));
    m.insert(pair<float,int>(.4,5));
    map<float,int>::reverse_iterator rend=m.rend();
    map<float,int>::iterator begin=m.begin();

    for ( rend=m.rbegin() ; rend != m.rend(); rend++ )
    cout << rend->first << " => " << rend->second << endl;
}
```

The output:

```
0.4 => 5
0.1 => 0
```

If `rend` was pointing to the first element, 0.1 => 0 would not be printed.

This is my example. You have to show what your code where you actually arrived at the conclusion that rend points to the first element.

Comment: Actually as I understood the question is that `rend()` and `begin()` points to the same element. However in your example you don't print `rend()` element

Comment: @ArtakBegnazaryan: That's because rend() is not suppose to be printed. It's like saying, let's try to access and print the space past the last element of the list. My example shows that since rend does not point to the first element, the loop does not stop at the first element, but stops when you reach the end. If rend was indeed equal to begin, the first element would not get printed because the loop would terminate on the equality.

Comment: just got my vote back :) The point is that I checked and printed the value of `rend()` and its really was equal to the value of `begin()` (I know that this is implementation dependent and not defined by standard). Your code proves that the `rend()` does not point to the same place as `begin()`, however their values can be equal.